# C++ - destructors

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor, dynamic

In the external C++ learning resource that I'm reading.

What is an example on this statement?

*When a variable goes out of scope, or a dynamically allocated variable is explicitly deleted using the delete keyword, the class destructor is called (if it exists) to help clean up the class before it is removed from memory.*

And, what do we mean by **dynamically allocated memory**?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm on the edge of voting to close all further questions from you on the grounds that you're not trying to learn anything anyway. (We _have_ been trying to rub your nose in your need to get a book quite thoroughly several times.)

Comment: @sbi: seconded - 53 questions to date, all on basic introductory C/C++ stuff, and no attempt to read a book...

Comment: As with all your other questions, this one was covered by the tutorial as well. See [section 7.9](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/).

Comment: I think you're supposed to read the *whole* tutorial before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples

> When a variable goes out of scope

```
void foo()
{
   MyClass C;
   C.callSomeMethod();
}  // C is here going out of scope
```

> or a dynamically allocated variable is
>   explicitly deleted using the delete
>   keyword

```
void foo()
{
  MyClass* C = new MyClass; // allocating on heap
  delete C; // deleting allocated memory
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's explained in your favorite C++ tutorial in [section 6.9](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/69-dynamic-memory-allocation-with-new-and-delete/).

Answer (score 1):

"dynamically allocated memory" means allocated via the new or new [] operator on the dynamical memory (usually the heap).

Answer (score -4):

dynamically allocated memory is a memory you allocate by yourself (calloc\malloc\new etc.). if you allocate memory (dynamiclly) - you're also responsible for releasing in (free)

for example,
int i; --> the compiller allocate the memory (static)

char *c;
c = malloc (8*sizeof(char)); (dynamic)

in C++ when you want to release the memory of the object (destroy the object) you can implement a routine that will be called before the object will be destroyed (free routine). it can be useful (for example, in order to release some resources like closing files)

Comment: Please don't teach using `malloc()` in C++! I add a downvote to this.

Comment: He asked what is it dynamically allocated memory - malloc is an example, I didn't say it is useful in C++... When I refereed to C++ - I've mentioned it.