# C++ - Strange output

Tags: c++, constructor

Following the example at the external C++ learning resource that I'm reading.

Which is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
class MyString
{
private:
char *m_pchString;
int m_nLength;

public:
MyString(const char *pchString="")
{
//find the length of the string
//plus "1" for a terminator
m_nLength=strlen(pchString)+1;
//allocate a buffer equal to this length
m_pchString=new char(m_nLength);
//copy the parameter into our internal buffer
strncpy(m_pchString,pchString,m_nLength);
//make sure the string is terminated
m_pchString[m_nLength-1]='\0';
}

~MyString() //destructor
{
//deallocate buffer
delete m_pchString;
//set m_pchString to null just in case
//m_pchString=0;
}

char* GetString()
{
return m_pchString;
}

int GetLength()
{
return m_nLength;
}
};

int main()
{
MyString cMyName("Abder-Rahman");
std::cout<<"My name is: "<<cMyName.GetString()<<std::endl;
return 0;
} //cMyName destructor is called here
```

The output is: `My name is: Abder-Rahman3`

Where did the **3** come from?

If I type:

> MyString cMyName("abc");

It simply returns `My name is: abc`

Why does **3** appear with `Abder-Rahman` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Dude! Will you ever stop advertising learncpp.com. Go get a textbook.

Comment: `m_pchString=new char(m_nLength)` should be `m_pchString=new char[m_nLength]` - I believe the former should at least emit a compilation warning.

Comment: Lol, 0 downvotes, 1 answer and 54+ questions. You're a leecher!

Comment: @SWEngineer, for me no 3 appears. @Neo, why should he?

Comment: @Max - Look at all the previous posts by SWE. All of them are somehow linked to learncpp.com .

Comment: @Neo: Oh, I overlooked that link this time and assumed it was a genuine posting for once. __Flagged for moderator's attention now.__

Comment: If these tutorials aren't helping you anymore than this, stop reading them. Find something else. Asking questions is encouraged, but asking us to explain every page of a tutorial guide is getting a little excessive. You're beginning to frustrate the people who are the most knowledgeable and could provide you with the most help. Showing some initiative and evidence that you've tried to figure these answers out yourself would be a welcome relief. Otherwise, do you own this website? If so, please stop spamming.

Comment: @Neo, I looked for 7 questions: 1 is connected to learncpp.com, 2 are connected to railstutorial.org, 1 links to vhochstein.wordpress.com, others don't link to anything. Anyway, is it not allowed?

Comment: @Neo, is it any problem if he decided to learn C++ from those tutorials? Is it more legitimate to ask a plethora of questions based on e.g. Stroustrup or whatever other well-known source? Of course it is a different issue if the material on learncpp.com is low quality, but then it is better to comment specifically on that. Anyway, even if these questions were an attempt to spam, I don't see them as a terribly efficient way to advertise that site - a tutorial which leaves this many open questions behind can't be good :-)

Comment: @Max, @Péter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773990/c-destructors That's been 40mins ago. As I said there, I've now started to vote to close his questions.

Comment: I apologize I went a little overboard, my comment almost looks like flaming. In my defense, SWE had been requested repeatedly to post meaningful questions.

Comment: @Péter: The code is mostly copied from the page linked to, except for some silly "typoes" which he added, and which should be easy to find with a simple diff program. (And that page really shows this class violating the Rule of Three. Is that low quality enough?)

Comment: Well, at least this question isn't as bad as the previous ones, although I wonder how all that errors got into the code.

Comment: @sbi, good point. At least the error I found is his own typo, not from the source page :-) Let's keep in mind this is a tutorial, where language concepts are introduced one by one. Assignment operator and copy constructor is dealt with later, in chapters 9.11-12. One can surely debate about the ideal ordering of topics, but there isn't necessarily a single way of presentation perfect for everyone.

Comment: @Péter: I beg to differ. How can you introduce a string class that manages its memory and _not_ explain the need to cctor and assop? That's so bad, it's almost evil.

Comment: @Péter Török. Actually, when I did what you mentioned by changing () to [], the "3" didn't appear :-)

Comment: @Cody Gray. I don't own this website, just using it as a resource for C++.

Comment: @Péter Török. No, this is not an attempt to spam, just using learcpp.com as a resource for C++ learning.

Comment: @ Péter Török. I think the tutorial learncpp.com is good, but the questions are due to some lack of knowledge in some issues.

Comment: @SWEngineer: __No, that tutorial is not good.__ What you linked to is a string class that will allow copying of strings, but will blow up if you do so. Please read my comment regarding the quality of C++ books to your earlier question. What I said applies even more so to websites, which (different than even the worst books) undergo no review process at all. The only good web resource for learning C++ I have heard of is Bruce Eckel's _Thinking in C++_, and that's actually a book which (due to its exposure to the community) has been reviewed extensively. Once more: __You will need a good book.__

Comment: @SWEngineer, glad I could help fixing your problem. Be it a lesson though that the problem was caused by your own sloppiness in copying the sample code :-) Such things of course have happened to most or all of us on SO - we are all humans. However, a good programmer learns from his/her mistakes and strives to avoid making the same error ever again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted here is different from that in the tutorial. It introduces at least two errors:

```
m_pchString=new char(m_nLength);
```

This should be:

```
m_pchString=new char[m_nLength];
```

The first one allocates a buffer for one character and initializes it with m_nLength.

Another error:

```
delete m_pchString;
```

It should be:

```
delete[] m_pchString;
```

Because you allocate an array (well, after you fix the first error, that is). The reason you got "3" in the name is because everything past the first character in the string is located in the memory that doesn't really belong to you so it got overwritten by something. Sometimes the program just crashes instead, sometimes it prints the correct result. That's UB for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor, when allocating memory for the internal pointer there is an error:

```
m_pchString=new char(m_nLength);
```

Means allocate a single character and initialize that character with the value `m_nLength`. Compare with:

```
m_pchString=new char[m_nLength];
```

That means dynamically allocate `m_nLength` characters without performing any initialization. At the same time, you need to change the call to `delete` to use `delete []` in the destructor, as you are dealing with arrays, and not single elements:

```
delete [] m_pchString;
```

As @sbi correctly points out, you should always follow the law of the three: if you need to provide a destructor, then you should also provide a copy constructor and assignment operator. Not doing so, means that your object can be copied with the implicitly defined versions of assignment and copy construction that will copy the pointers, but not the memory. Then the destructor will be called at some point, and the second copy to call the destructor will end up in undefined behavior and most probably segmentation fault.